# postgres not starting after reboot on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, startup-scripts

I'm not familiar with ubuntu (raring), so could someone help me please:

I'm using postgresql 9.1 from apt. It installed the appropriate init script in `/etc/init.d/postgresql`. I can start the server manually using the script. However, postgres is not started on boot. I issued a `update-rc.d postgresql defaults` and `update-rc.d postgresql enable` (as root) but that did not help.

Is there a specific boot log as i could not find anything in syslog? Thanks guys

EDIT2: OK, the problem seems to be a sysvinit vs. upstart problem. If I remove the symlinks in `/etc/rcX`:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f remove postgresql
```

and add a [upstart script](https://gist.github.com/bradleyayers/1660177) to start postgresql, it starts on boot as expected. As the postgresql is from the official apt repo I wonder why it's not working out of the box?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running?. IMHO the syntax is  `sudo update-rc.d postgresql defaults`.

Comment: Please have a look at the /var/log/daemon.log and /var/log/postgresql/ if there is any hind, and provide the last log-lines after reboot of the files.

Comment: Ubuntu version is a raring 32 cloud image. `/var/log/daemon.log` does not exist and `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log` does not say anything after the last shutdown. It just seems to not start automatically.

Comment: That `update-rc.d` should have created symlinks from `/etc/init.d/postgresql` to `/etc/rc2.d/Sxy-postgresql`, where xy is a number to arrange the start order. There should be other entries in rc3.d rc5.d. Can you you see these entries?

Comment: Yes, edited the question to include that

Comment: I have a similar issue, I know that my network card is not yet configured when postgresql try to start. I will find out how to solve it. Maybe it is the same issue for you? Try issue `systemctl status postgresql@<version>-<cluster>.service` to check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using server or desktop version.

Normally Postgres work perfectly out the box on ubuntu, but i always use ubuntu server LTS.  I think to that issue was caused for some inconsistence on the raring version installer.